# If $\int_{0+}^{1-} |f(x)|^p dx$ converges for some $p > 1$, then$\int_{0+}^{1-} |f(x)| dx$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Assume $f$ is continuous on $(0, 1)$. Prove that if $\int_{0+}^{1-} |f(x)|^p dx$ converges for some $p > 1$, then$\int_{0+}^{1-} |f(x)| dx$ converges.

I imagine I would have to use Young's inequality for this, but I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can simply use the inequality $a\le a^p$ for all $a>1$, since only "large" values can cause a problem for convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Use that, for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, $$|f(x)|\leqslant1+|f(x)|^p$$ The continuity of $f$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use [holder-inequality](/questions/tagged/holder-inequality).

$$\int_{0+}^{1-} |f(x)| \cdot 1 dx \le \left(\int_{0+}^{1-} |f(x)|^p dx \right)^{1/p} \left(\int_{0+}^{1-} 1^q dx \right)^{1/q},$$

where $\dfrac1p + \dfrac1q = 1$.